# List of Pennsylvania Nursing Schools their Addresses, Enrollment, Graduation Rates?

Tags: data-request, usa, medical, state

I'm looking for a list of nursing schools in Pennsylvania (PA) along with the addresses, enrollment, and graduation rates.  Preferably in a non-scrapable format like JSON or CSV.

Comment: Probably you'll have to contact: http://www.dos.pa.gov/ProfessionalLicensing/BoardsCommissions/Nursing/Pages/default.aspx